# Resolve service Using DI in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I have used autofac ,mvc 4.0 .
I have registered the interfaces and modules in Application_Start of my mvc 4.0 application.
I have also used properties auto wired eg

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
//Other codes...
builder.RegisterType<Service>()
                .As<IService>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
                .PropertiesAutowired());
      builder.RegisterControllers(typeof (MvcApplication).Assembly)
                    .PropertiesAutowired();
...
}
```

However The dependencies are not resolved in the startup class, and the object is always null .

```
 public class Startup
    {
    public IService MyService { get; set; }
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            MyService.SomeMetod(3, "");
        }
     }
```

In above code I was expecting MyService to be an object , but its not so it is always null, Am I doing something wrong Please Help.

Please note that the di is working in controllers , it is not working in the startup class only !

Comment: In order for your dependency to be injected into your `Startup` class, the class that created the instance of the calling class would need to have been created by your DI container.  If it isn't, it won't work :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autofac Injection of data into OWIN Startup class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654149/autofac-injection-of-data-into-owin-startup-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was expecting AutoFac to resolve dependency automatically as it does in the controller classes , It was solved using manual resolution as following:

```
 var myService = (IService)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IService ));
```

Comment: If you call .GetService, or something similar on your code, it is usually a sign you are "doing it wrong". You are binding your Startup class to the dependency injection code, which should stay away from inside your "standard code". A better solution is to register the Startup class for dependency injection, as of my answer below. IMO.